# Openresty custom path to @proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, google-cloud-platform, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, openresty

I'm trying to request url like https://example.com/project1/app1/ from GCP https load balancer and on instance I'm using openresty reverse proxy with access_by_lua module which is passing to http://localhost:8000. On the browser I'm getting 404 error "not found" which is obvious because this path /project1/app1/ doesn't exist.

My question is: is there any way to reach to http://localhost:8000 directly with openresty lua rewrite or redirect module?

I'm a newbie and haven't any knowledge about openresty module.

I would appreciate if you add your thoughts or comments ?

Many thanks,adam